# What is the definition of $Sha(E/K)[\phi]$ for elliptic curves?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $\phi: E \to E'$ be isogeny between elliptic curves.
Let $K$ be a number field. Let $Sha(E/K)$ be a Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curve $E/K$.What is the definition of $Sha(E/K)[\phi]$ ?

Silverman's book 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves' deals with this group, but I think there is no definition of $Sha(E/K)[\phi]$.

I think the definition is $Sha(E/K)[\phi]=ker(H^1(G_K,E(K)[\phi])\to \prod H^1(G_{K_v},E(K_v)[\phi]))$.

Is my definition correct ?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you've written is closer to the definition of $\mathrm{Sel}_\phi(E) = \ker(H^1(G_K, E[\phi])\to \prod H^1(G_{K_v}, E))$. $\mathrm{Sha}(E/K)[\phi]$ is $\ker (H^1(G_K, E)[\phi] \to \prod H^1(G_{K_v}, E))$.

Comment: @Mathmo123. Could you tell me the definition of $H^1(G_{K},E)[\phi]$ ? This should be a kennel of the induced map of $\phi$ on $E$, but  I don't understand what the induce map of $\phi$ on $H^1(G_K,E)$.

Comment: The simplest definition is just the kernel of the map $H^1(G_K, E)\to H^1(G_K, E')$ that takes a cocycle $G_K\to E$ to $G_K\to E\to E'$. You can check that this is well defined.

Comment: @Mathmo$123$ Is the $X=ker(H^1(G_K,E)[\phi]\to \prod H^1(G_{K_v},E)[\phi])$ also the same definition of $Sha(E/K)[\phi]$ ? It is obvious that $X\subset Sha(E/K)$, but does the converse inclusion holds in general ? ( I think no because there is no reason the inverse inclusion holds, but I cannot give counterexamples)

Comment: @Mathmo123. I'm sticking with this for more than a week.

Comment: I think they should be the same. The image of the lhs always lands in the rhs anyway